# Should I create a Model & DAO for this in my Java web application?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I have the following action servlet and was wondering if I should create a model called `supervisor` and a corresponing supervisorDAO as I did for program?  The programDAO puts multiple program model beans into the returned arraylist.  For supervisors, I am using a general input/output database utility to get an arraylist of hashmaps (retALM) for any passed in SQL string.  The supervisor list is used to create a select pulldown on the html form.

The concern I have is storing the sql string in the action servlet.  I'm not sure it warrants creating a supervisor model and DAO if I have a User model and UserDAO class.  Actually after typing this post, I further beleive that is not the right approach.  So it is down to either leaving it the way I have it below or adding  the `supervisor` SQL call to get a list of supervisors in the UserDAO class since a user can be a supervisor.  I welcome other critiques to my action servlet approach below as well.

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, 
    IOException {
    ProgramDAO prgDAO = new ProgramDAO();
    STKUser authenticatedUser = (STKUser) request.getSession().getAttribute("STKUserSession");
    List programs = null;
    List supervisors = null;

    try {
        programs = prgDAO.getProgramList(authenticatedUser);
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        request.setAttribute("message", e);
    }

    String strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT phonebook.badge, phonebook.lname, phonebook.fname FROM phonebook 
        WHERE phonebook.badge IN (SELECT DISTINCT phonebook.ata_badge FROM phonebook WHERE 
        phonebook.dept='" + authenticatedUser.getDepartment() + "') ORDER BY lname";
    supervisors = General_IO.retALM(strSQL);

    request.setAttribute("supervisors", supervisors);
    request.setAttribute("programs", programs);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("views/commitment_template.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I recommend not using the servlet API directly. With servlets, you have to write a lot of code to do simple parameter handling. Servlets are also hard to test with unit tests. There are many web action frameworks to choose from, including WebWork, Stripes and Spring MVC.

Comment: I appreciate the framework suggestions. Beleive me, I would love to use one of them. But I work for a large corporation with an IT group that controls the webserver. We are 8 years behind in using any new technology and I am not allowed to install any software/framework myself on the server. They handcuff us with development.  :(  I do have a folder in the class path and might be able to sidestep some IT rules and drop some jars there provided it will run on our antiquated server (jsp 1.2, java 1.4, web module 2.3)

Comment: You don't need to install something on the server to use these frameworks; you just include jars on the classpath. If they deploy your application via a WAR file, then it's just one more jar to package. If the IT department pushes back, I suggest talking about all of the security and performance implications of rolling this yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Thats another issue.  We are not set up to deploy WAR files.  At leaset IT says they don't have a process to do WAR deployment for individual developers.  When I drop a class file in a folder in the class path, I am sort of at the mercy of the nightly server reboots.  Is there a way to get the server to reload my classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your supervisors are users and you have a UserDAO, then perhaps your UserDAO should have a getSupervisors() method, or maybe a getSupervisors(String dept) method.

Never, ever, ever construct SQL by string concatenation, its just asking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach that I decided on taking - adding a getSupervisorByDept(authenticatedUser user) method to my UserDAO.  In all my DAO's I use prepared statements to prevent sql injection.  The above sql is not concatenating a request parameter so I felt it was OK in that context.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the motivations for the [DAO pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html). In short, it is used to abstract out the way your data is accessed. If used properly, your servlet shouldn't have to include SQL.

I also suggest using a persistance API like JPA or JDO to access your objects. Building your own SQL for every type of data access is tedious, error prone, and often inefficent.

Separately from how you retrieve your data is the question of how you model your data. Since supervisor is a user, presumably with all the attributes of a user (name, employee ID, a supervisor) it probably makes sense to store those attributes in the same table you store the user data.

Comment: thanks. Unable to use persistance API like JPA or JDO since I am at the mercy of what our IT dept gives us developers.

Comment: The IT department won't let you include your own jar?  Its time to communicate the requirements of Java development to them.  BTW, hibernate is another option if they allow it.

Comment: @Peter I do have a folder in the classpath. So I might be able to sidestep some IT rules and drop some jars provided they will run on our antiquated server (jsp 1.2, java 1.4, web module 2.3)

Comment: All of these frameworks are jars!  You may have to use an older version to work with your target platform and might not be able to use the full suite if it requires server configuration changes that your company doesn't allow, but certainly the persistence layer can be handled this way.